# Converting a function from php to python

Tags: php, python, function

I am trying to convert this php function

```
function strpos_r($haystack, $needle)
{
    if(strlen($needle) > strlen($haystack))
        trigger_error(sprintf("%s: length of argument 2 must be <= argument 1", __FUNCTION__), E_USER_WARNING);

    $seeks = array();
    while($seek = strrpos($haystack, $needle))
    {
        array_push($seeks, $seek);
        $haystack = substr($haystack, 0, $seek);
    }
    return $seeks;
}
```

I have written this python function, but is not working as expected.

```
def strposR(haystack, needle):
    if strlen(needle) > strlen(haystack):
        sys.stderr.write("length of argument 2 must be <= argument 1")
    seeks = []
    seek = 0
    while seek == haystack.rfind(needle):
        seeks.append(seek)
        haystack = haystack[0:seek]
    return seeks
def strlen(x):
    return len(x)
```

What I am doing wrong? Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the point of the `strlen` function?

Comment: What is the expected output for an input, and what are you getting? I'm not a PHP expert, but the two seem fairly equivalent at first glance.

Comment: shouldnt strlen just be len in python?

Comment: wild guess: the while argument, == is comparison not assignent, and the boolean interpretation of an assignment is probably not what you want there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
def strpos_r(haystack, needle):
    positions = []
    position = haystack.rfind(needle)

    while position != -1:
        positions.append(position)
        haystack = haystack[:position]
        position = haystack.rfind(needle)

    return positions
```

Also, functions should not really handle input errors for you. You usually just `return False` or let the function throw an execution error.

Comment: This python version is not equivalent to the php-version, see my post for why, and we shouldn't even get started talking about the more *"pythonic solution"*

Comment: The code chunks shouldn't be equivalent. Python's syntax is much neater and is easier to read.

Comment: They should be equivalent in terms of results, they are not.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: as said; see my post, also; the *"pythonitc solution"* will act.. mad

Comment: So why would I include a bug in the Python code?

Comment: 1. the algorithms should be equivalent, so you have no choice 2. have you actually thought about what the pythonic version will yield?

Comment: I have all the choices I want. The algorithms should accomplish the same goal, not be direct copies of one another. If the PHP code has a bug, I don't care to translate it to the Python code. As for the Pythonic solution, what's wrong with it?

Comment: ... if you cannot see it without running the snippet I only got one option for you; run it and see what will happen, but as a hint: using haystack as the condition in your *while* is just.. well, it ain't gonna work now will it? haystack[:ret_val_of_unsuccessful_string_rfind] will effectively shift of one character at a time

Comment: As you are so fluent in python you should try it yourself. (yes, I had time to see your original comment)..

Comment: Don't be a snob. I tested my code with a faulty test string that happened to work with both the generator expression and the original Python code. I think it was `a a a` with a search string of `a`.

Comment: *"Don't be a snob."* says the fluent python developer who always tests his code to make sure it's correct, *"don't be a snob"* says the fluent python developer who can't even honestly admit when he was wrong. Sure, I'm a snob - but you are an ass for not taking what people (in this case I) write seriously, I wouldn't say that something is wrong with your snippets if they are correct.

Comment: Do you not see my previous comment? I admitted that I was wrong. I tested my code with a faulty test string and fixed it thanks to your input. If you don't take the time to setup lengthy arguments with people over mistakes in their code, maybe I would've taken your comment more seriously. Would saying *"Hey bro, your generator function won't work properly because `haystack[:-1]` will not return an empty copy of the string* be much more difficult than getting into a petty argument about Python code? I'm done with this argument, as there is nothing more to be said.

Comment: *Hey bro, your generator function still won't work properly because you will `yield index` even though index is equal to `-1`.*

Comment: Thanks. Adding in the other conditional logic would make it just as complex as the original translated Python code, so there is little use in rewriting the code as a generator.

Answer (score 3):

#### WARNING(s)

1. `strrpos` and `string.rfind` doesn't return the same values when the needle cannot be located. In php `strrpos` returns **false**, but python's `string.rfind` returns **-1**!
2. The *while-conditional* in the php version doesn't use strict comparison and therefore the function won't store the offset `0` in the resulting array if the needle is found there, to fix this issue the code should have been written as:

   `while (($seek = strrpos ($haystack, $needle)) !== false)`

---

#### The root of your problem..

```
while($seek = strrpos($haystack, $needle)) # PHP
while seek == haystack.rfind(needle):      # python
```

The above two lines does not provide the equivalent functionality, the php-condition is equivalent to writing:

```
while (($seek = strrpos ($haystack, $needle)) != false)
```

---

I'd change your python loop into:

```
while True:
  seek = haystack.rfind(needle)
 
  if seek == -1:
    break

  if seek ==  0: # because of mentioned bug in the php version
    break

  seeks.append(seek)
  haystack = haystack[0:seek]
```

Comment: I would change `while 1` to `while True` and remove that semicolon after `break`.

Answer (score 1):

A few small changes:

```
def strposR(haystack, needle):
    if len(needle) > len(haystack):
        sys.stderr.write("length of argument 2 must be <= argument 1")
    seeks = []
    seek = haystack.rfind(needle)
    while seek != -1:
        seeks.append(seek)
        haystack = haystack[0:seek]
        seek = haystack.rfind(needle)
    return seeks
```